# Install JFLEX ON MAC

Tags: macos, jflex

Can someone tell me how I can install jflex (The Fast Scanner Generator for Java) on my Mac? I searched everywhere on google and I can't find it.

Can you help me ?

Comment: What about the "Installing JFlex" right on the homepage? http://jflex.de/installing.html

Comment: And you don't even need to install JFlex if you use Maven (disclaimer: I wrote the maven-jflex-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate Mac installer, but you can use the same commands as on Linux.

The installation instructions on http://jflex.de/installing.html now mention this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having Brew installed and setup in your Mac,

Use this command: `brew install jflex`

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install jflex
```

Worked for me, still learning how to use this in class so I'm not sure how to use it just yet.